# Add a "return" statement to this callback

Tags: javascript, sonarcloud

I pushed some third party code to our Repo and got this errormessage from Sonar Cloud;
"Add a "return" statement to this callback."

I added the return statement, but still got the same error.

I also tried to replace the comma after the forEach function with a semicolon.

THIS IS THE BEGINNING CODE:

```
o.map(function (n) {
    t.setPercentBar(n, e);
});
```

THIS IS WHAT I DID:

```
o.map(function (n) {
    return t.setPercentBar(n, e);
});
```

This is the function where the map function is inside:

```
fillPercentBar: function (e) {
            var t = this,
              n = r(".progress-action"),
              o = [];
            Object.values(n).forEach(function (e) {
              o.push(e.id);
            }),
              o.map(function (n) {
                t.setPercentBar(n, e);
              });
          },
```

Comment: Map should be used to return a new (or "mapped") instance of each object, you just want to call a method. Checkout `o.forEach()` instead.